# Swapping buffers multiple times in one function (OpenGL and C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer, swap

I'm using an OpenGL display function that contains the following lines of code:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

//Draw some stuff

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPopMatrix();
glutSwapBuffers();
```

However, I'm applying this code multiple times throughout the function. What I want to happen is for it to draw something, respond to the user's input, draw something else, respond to the user's input again and finally draw one last thing. Is it considered acceptable practice to call "glutSwapBuffers" multiple times in the same function? If it's not a huge problem, is there a way to make it properly display the final drawing? It draws the first two pictures that I want it to, but the third time the screen just stays white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you make a loop

check for input at the beginning of the loop and then update variables and then draw once depending on those variables and restart the loop.

if no input comes in then the variables that don't depend on time will remain the same and what you draw will remain the same.